# How to verify value of first google search result using Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

How can I do the following in Robot Framework: assert that first result of google search for 'stackoverflow.com' is stackoverflow.com website? Currently learning Robot framework, using Python and Selenium2Library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Should Be Equal As Strings` keyword :

```
  Open Browser   https://www.google.com/  chrome
  Maximize Browser Window
  Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//input[contains(@class,'gLFyf')]
  Input Text    xpath=//input[contains(@class,'gLFyf')]    stackoverflow.com
  Press Keys    xpath=//input[contains(@class,'gLFyf')]    ENTER  
  ${first_result}=    Get Text    xpath=(//*[contains(@class,'LC20lb ')])[1]
  Should Be Equal As Strings    ${first_result}     Stack Overflow - Where 
  Developers Learn, Share, & Build ...
```